# What is the difference between 100mb and 1gb connection for servers

Tags: performance, internet

is there a big difference  between 100mb and 1gb for server internet connection speed

Comment: If you need to ask, you probably shouldn't be the one making the decision.

Comment: "server internet connection speed", I think is confusing people, if you have a server that has a 1gb nic and its connected to a 1gb switch but it only has a 1mb internet connection then a 1gb nic is not going to make a difference as far as internet speeds are concerned.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on how many people are using this connection and what they're doing. At its peak, 1gb will obviously be able to handle 10 times as much traffic than 100mb.

If you're transferring a lot of data between servers often, then, yes, you will notice a difference.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on how much data you're transferring, and how fast you want it done :-) if you need to transfer/stream 1gb+ files often (think file servers, streaming media servers, high load SQL databases, etc.) ... then yeah, it's a big difference

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not too relevant for the (external) Internet connection, but might well make a difference for inter-server communication within your data center (between app server and database server for example).

Answer (score 1):

Usually your server hard-drives can't supply that much data for long time, so it basically doesn't mean a lot unless you know what you're doing - both hardware wise, and software wise.

Comment: content sometimes is served directly from RAM, also remember about disk caching on RAM... so - your point is invalid :) for example, on server memcache traffic is ~200 mb/s while there is just 2 desktop SATA drives inside .

Comment: @Kristaps, you're overstepping a bit to say his point is "invalid". It might be the case that the webserver is only serving files much too large to fit in RAM (or perhaps the server has very little RAM). There's plenty of possibilities where the point is valid.